# Install4j create Launcher from second File Set

Tags: install4j, launcher

i have a Project and want to create a Launcher. But the Launcher i want to create is from a different FileSet as Default file set.

On Configuration i selected the FileSet i want to use

On "Configure Java invocation" i added the jar Archive as Class Path. 
But if i want to select the Main Class it gives me the following Error

**Empty class path**

Why the Main Class is not detected. If i try it with the default file set it detects the Main Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 7.0.4. In the meantime, you can enter your main class manually into the text field.